# Can I use YouTube video url to play it in exoplayer and update it everyday

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I’m beginner level coder I’m a trying to build an application to take video from the YouTube put it on the recycler view and on click plays the video in the exoplayer. And also update the recycler view when a new video is uploaded. I’ll be adding new video regularly and needs to be updated inside the app.

Please help!!!

I’ve tried using exoplayer but I didn’t knew it was migrated until now (like I said I am newbie at this) so please help me!